# MySQL 1052 in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

Нужно вывести номера деталей из двух разных таблиц. Перепробовал всё и просмотрел все возможные пути решения, но у меня не получается сделать один вывод из двух таблиц.

```
mysql> select item_number from curcuma.details, curcuma.products;
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'item_number' in field list is ambiguous
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что в обеих таблицах есть поле с таким именем, и сервер не знает, какое из них показывать. Добавьте алиас конкретной таблицы к имени поля выходного набора. PS. А где условия связывания-то?

Comment: Условия таковы Выдать номера деталей, поставляемых для какого-либо изделия из Лондона. примерное представление того, что я делаю тут -davaiknam.ru/text/sozdanie-i-modifikaciya-bazi-dannih-i-tablic исходя из этого надо запросить у двух таблиц информацию про номера деталей из лондона

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT details.item_number as details_item_number, products.item_number as products_item_number  
FROM curcuma.details, curcuma.products;
```

Если надо сделать вывод вертикально, то можно использовать `UNION/UNION ALL`